# EBS payment gateway integration using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, integration, payment-gateway

i need to integrate ebs payment gateway. i am searching lot but i could find the solution. 
Response is provided using POST method to the URL defined under ReturnURL parameter in the payment request. `$response['ResponseCode'] == 0` means transaction successfully completed. Other than 0 value transactions failed. I can't find `$response['ResponseCode'] == 0`.

here my code

```
if(isset($_GET['DR'])) {
 require('Rc43.php');
 $DR = preg_replace("/\s/","+",$_GET['DR']);

 $rc4 = new Crypt_RC4($secret_key);
 $QueryString = base64_decode($DR);
 $rc4->decrypt($QueryString);
 $QueryString = split('&',$QueryString);

 $response = array();
 foreach($QueryString as $param){
    $param = split('=',$param);
    $response[$param[0]] = urldecode($param[1]);
 }
}
```

Comment: what issue are you having?

Comment: just i find the article its help me lot

Comment: i am not getting response code

Comment: http://www.vaaah.com/php/view/PaymentGateways/21/EBS-payment-gateway-integration-using-PHP

Answer (score 0):

I would understand how exactly the integration to EBC is done and look at one of the existing Broadleaf Payment modules as a template.

For example:

```
- Does EBC provide an API for direct server to server communication? (i.e. the Credit Card information is passed to your server and then relayed to the gateway? If so, take a look at http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/curre ... odule.html
- Does EBC provide a mechanism for a Transparent Redirect or Silent Post? (i.e. the Credit Card form is sent directly to EBC thereby bypassing the merchant servers? If so, take a look at http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/curre ... e.net.html
- Does EBC provide a mechanism for a Hosted Order Page? (i.e. you get redirected to EBC's servers to enter your credit card information. If so, take a look at http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/curre ... odule.html)
```

The many different integration options that the Payment Gateway provides will determine how Broadleaf should integrate with it.
Hope that helps.

Reference : http://www.fetchflow.com/blog/authorize-net-invoicing